# run time error 1004: the method 'Activate' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that allows users to input data and then outputs this data in a presentable format as a PDF.  It does this by opening up a separate workbook which is saved on a local drive on all users' PCs and copies data from the current workbook into this separate workbook. It then activates each sheet in the new workbook (this is done as some of the sheets have events hanging off them, and we want to make sure they trigger). Finally the new workbook is saved as a PDF. Code as follows:

```
Dim qwb As Workbook

Set qwb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Program Files\Workbook2", Editable:=False)

qwb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Range1").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Range1").Value
        

With qwb
    .Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    .Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    .Worksheets("Sheet1").Visible = xlVeryHidden
End With
qwb.Save
qwb.Close savechanges:=False
```

A couple of users have recently been upgraded to office 2016, and since then the code hasn't worked for them - they reported getting a 'File not Found' error despite the workbook definitely existing on their PCs. When I opened up the code on their machines I saw the error was actually the one in the title, appearing on the 'Worksheets.Activate' lines. The qwb workbook was open, the line above where the data was copied over was working fine, and checking in the immediate window showed that 'qwb' was definitely still set to the new workbook.

Any ideas what's causing the error and how to get round it?

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to activate the workbook first. You could also call the events themselves and skip the activations.

Comment: Normally `Activate` is not needed.

Comment: I've tried activating the workbook first but still the same error unfortunately. I'll have a look at calling the events without activating the sheets, thanks